# Helical motion of a charge in magnetic and electric field

Tags: magnetic-fields, kinematics, electric-fields

Suppose there is a positive charge undergoing circular motion in the x-y plane because of a magnetic field acting in the negative z direction. If a uniform electric field is switched on in the same direction as the magnetic field,  will the pitch of the helical motion be uniform?
By my understanding it should be because the the velocity component in the x y plane remains unchanged.
But my book seems to disagree, stating that it will be helix with a nonuniform pitch. 
So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The pitch is the distance moved along the $z$ axis in one revolution in the $xy$ plane. If the magnetic field is constant then the time taken for one revolution $T$ will be constant so the pitch is $v_zT$, where $v_z$ is the velocity along the $z$ axis.

The helix will have a constant pitch if and only if the velocity along the $z$ axis is constant. If you have a constant field $E_z$ then you have a constant force $F_z = QE_z$ and therefore a constant acceleration $a_z = QE_z/m$. This means the velocity increases linearly with time and therefore the pitch increases linearly with time.

Comment: This answer treats the non-relativistic case nicely.  Note, however, that (as is usually the case) things get a little more complicated when the particle starts getting relativistic.  In particular, the amount of time $T$ required to make one circuit is no longer constant, but increases as the particle moves faster in the $z$-direction.